# Merge two dataframes with subheaders

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have my first dataframe that has countries as headers and infected and death values as subheaders,

```
df
Dates       Antigua & Barbuda      Australia
          Infected      Dead      Infected   Dead
2020-01-22    0          0            0        0...
2020-01-23    0          0            0        0...
...
```

then I have my second dataframe,

```
df_indicators
Dates       Location      indicator_1      indicator_2 .....
2020-04-24  Afghanistan      0                  0
2020-04-25  Afghanistan      0                  0
...
2020-04-24  Yemen            0                  0
2020-04-25  Yemen            0                  0
```

I want to merge the dataframes so that the indicator columns become subheaders of the countries column like in `df` with the infected and dead subheaders.

What I want to produce is something like this,

```
df_merge
Dates        Antigua & Barbuda
        Infected    Dead   indicator_1   indicator_2....
2020-04-24  0         0        0             0...
```

There are so many indicators that are all named something different that I don't feel I can call them all so not sure if theres a way I can do this easily.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are duplicates first aggregate by `mean` and then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html):

```
df2 = df_indicators.groupby(['Dates','Location']).mean().unstack().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
```

Or with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df2 = (df.pivot_table(index='Dates', columns='Location', aggfunc='mean')
         .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1))
```

And last join with sorting `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. I do get this error however, 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape' which is due to there being duplicates in both the 'Dates' and 'Location' column could I use a groupby function in anyway to fix this?

Comment: @RhysJones - answer was edited.

Comment: This has got passed the issue but now when I concat, the infected and dead columns from df disapear after concat.

Comment: @RhysJones - if test after `df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`  what get `print (df.columns.level[1])` ?

Comment: 'AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'level''

Comment: @RhysJones - and `print (df.columns.levels1])` ?